# Go to line with `<line><leader>` without timeout

Tags: leader

I currently have

```
nnoremap <leader> G
```

in my `.vimrc` so I can go to line 123 by typing `123<leader>`.

However, since I have other leader combinations, such as `<leader>u`, the line jump happens only after a second.

I know how to reduce this timeout, but I don't really want to do that since it would make it harder for me to use `<leader>u` when I actually want to.

I would also be happy to type `<leader>123` if that is easier to accomplish.

Comment: That key mapping is not working for me. How is it supposed to work?

Answer (score 1):

You may do 
`nnoremap <leader><leader> G`.

Then just type the linenumber and double click the leaderkey.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map <buffer> <nowait>` to stop receiving more keys and execute the map immediately. Note `<nowait>` only has effect when defined for buffer-local maps. See `:h map-nowait`.

For example:

```
nmap ff :echo 'ff'<cr>
nmap <buffer> <nowait> f +
set timeout
set timeoutlen=3000
```

Then you can feel the difference.

To run `ff`, you need to use `:normal ff`

Comment: I did `noremap <nowait> <leader> G` and still got the delay

Comment: Please see my edit